# Non-clickable areas in multi-line HTMLanchors

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to prevent non-clickable area between lines in a multi-line html anchor tag? Here in this example I use line height 1.5 and you can't click between lines.

I know in html5 we can put block-level tags in anchor like `<a><div>Link</div></a>` but the problem is this part of content can be edited by users and I can't ask them to write their anchor links like this. Is it possible to fix this issue with `css` only?

**CSS:**

```
a {
    line-height:1.5em;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">This is a <br> multiline anchor</a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="#">This is a very long anchor displayed as a multiline anchor without BR</a>
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/F52uY/2/

Comment: The thing is that there are legitimate cases that must not be clickable.. for example how to handle this case http://jsfiddle.net/F52uY/5/ ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli that's not a problem because this is going to be used for a specific css class only for anchors which acts as a colored button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set `display: inline-block;` or `display: block` to `a`, and then it will be clickable.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RMXfc/

Or you can increase `padding` and set negative `margin` at the same time. This will reduce gap.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/693z4/

Comment: it will not work when the text is in the normal flow of a sentence. example at http://jsfiddle.net/F52uY/8/

Answer (score 2):

If you give your anchor tags a `display: block;` you will have a solid clickable area.

```
a {
  line-height:1.5em;
  display: block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F52uY/4/)

One problem with `display: block;` is without a specified width, then entire 100% width is clickable.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to approximate it without messing with the rest of the layout of your text (*including the surrounding text of the link*) is to add some top/bottom paddings to these links..

So adding `padding:3px 0;` to your code would fix the issue.
(*it will require adjusting, though, in relation to your `font-size` and `line-height`*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/F52uY/7/